# Adding new customer to Quickbooks 2013

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have an app that adds customers to Quickbooks 2013, and using previous versions of the SDK (11) and Quickbooks (2012) if there wasn't a new customer, it just automatically added it. With upgrading to QB 2013 and the latest version of the SDK (12) I'm getting a message saying that I need to add the customer to Quickbooks first. The only code I changed/added in my app was to add the appropriate references to the new SDK. Is there a possible solution? Sorry for not posting code, I just inherited this app and am still figuring things out.

Comment: The behavior of the SDK has *always* been that you MUST add the customer first. Double-check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change to the behavior of the CustomerMod message for SDK 12. It appears you missed something when you tested the SDK 11 version of the add-on: either the customer already existed, or the code was adding the customer for you.

Comment: Do you know why earlier versions of Quickbooks allowed us to add customers that didn't exist yet? I'll have to dig through our code to find out exactly what we were doing with earlier versions-I just inherited this mass of code starting a new job, and its rather uncommented and undocumented. I'm guessing the code allowed us to do that, and QB 2013 finally closed that loophole.

Comment: Let me be clear: I don't agree with your assessment. QB 2013 didn't close any loopholes in this area. As you can see by the comment on this question @Keith Palmer agrees with me.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm very new to the Quickbooks SDK, Quickbooks in general, and developing business apps with C#. I'm not all familiar with how they work on a deep level, like I've been doing it for years. Its also taking me time to be able to grok a 7000 line program that I inherited, with zero commenting or documentation. I'm undoubtedly getting terminology and processes wrong.

Comment: No worries. I have full sympathy for your situation and there's no question that it can be very difficult for any of us to understand the behavior of a legacy system. My hope is that having a better understanding of what QuickBooks is doing will help you untangle this mess. Don't forget the words of Sherlock Holmes:"when you remove the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."